# How to update queryset value in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have written a python script in my project. I want to update the value of a field.

Here are my modes

```
class News_Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    info = models.TextField(blank=False)
    image = models.FileField()
    website = models.TextField()
    total_star = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_user = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Count(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(News_Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.channelId.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
```

This is my python script:

```
from feed.models import Count, News_Channel


def run():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        news_channel = Count.objects.filter(channelId=i)
        total_rate = 0
        for rate in news_channel:
            total_rate += rate.rate
        print(total_rate)
        object = News_Channel.objects.filter(id=i)
        print(total_rate)
        print("before",object[0].total_star,total_rate)
        object[0].total_star = total_rate
        print("after", object[0].total_star)
        object.update()
```

After counting the total_rate from the Count table I want to update the total star value in News_Channel table. I am failing to do so and get the data before the update and after the update as zero. Although total_rate has value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `object` in your case is a queryset, and after you attempt to update `object[0]`, you don't store the results in the db, and don't refresh the queryset. To get it to work you should pass the field you want to update into the update method.

So, try this:

```
def run():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        news_channel = Count.objects.filter(channelId=i)
        total_rate = 0
        for rate in news_channel:
            total_rate += rate.rate
        print(total_rate)
        object = News_Channel.objects.filter(id=i)
        print(total_rate)
        print("before",object[0].total_star,total_rate)
        object.update(total_star=total_rate)
        print("after", object[0].total_star)
```

Answer (score 12):

## The problem

The reason why this fails is because here `object` is a `QuerySet` of `News_Channel`s, yeah that `QuerySet` might contain exactly one `News_Channel`, but that is irrelevant.

If you then use `object[0]` you make a query to the database to fetch the first element and deserialize it into a `News_Channel` object. Then you set the `total_star` of that object, but you *never* save that object. You only call `.update()` on the *entire* queryset, resulting in another *independent* query.

You can fix this with:

```
objects = News_Channel.objects.filter(id=i)
object = objects[0]
object.total_star = total_rate
object.save()
```

Or given you do not need any validation, you can boost performance with:

```
News_Channel.objects.filter(id=i).update(total_star=total_rate)
```

## Updating *all* `News_Channel`s

If you want to update *all* `News_Channel`s, you actually better use a `Subquery` here:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Sum, Subquery

subq = Subquery(
    Count.objects.filter(
        channelId=OuterRef('id')
    ).annotate(
        total_rate=Sum('rate')
    ).order_by('channelId').values('total_rate')[:1]
)

News_Channel.objects.update(total_star=subq)
```

Answer (score 2):

`News_Channel.total_star` can be calculated by using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
news_channel_obj.count_set.aggregate(total_star=Sum('rate'))['total_star']
```

You can then either use this in your script:

```
object.total_star = object.count_set.aggregate(total_star=Sum('rate'))['total_star']
```

Or if you do not need to cache this value because performance is not an issue, you can remove the total_star field and add it as a property on the `News_Channel` model

```
@property
def total_star(self):
    return self.count_set.aggregate(total_star=Sum('rate'))['total_star']
```